# Calculating Overtime for multiple shift on 24 hour format using SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this table, define for shits:

```
ShiftCode ShiftInTime  ShiftOutTime
    1       09:00         17:30
    2       06:00         14:00
    3       14:00         22:00
    4       22:00         06:00
```

Now, An Employee has InTime & OutTime like., 08:58:00.000,18:45:00.000
I have to calculate overtime for every shift define in table.
I am using this query to calculate the overtime:-

```
DECLARE @OTHours NUMERIC(18,2)    
SET @OTHours=(CASE WHEN @OutTime<=@ShiftOutTime THEN 0 ELSE   ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@ShiftOutTime,@OutTime))/60) END)
```

But no overtime is calculating for the last shift.
Please Help.

Comment: What do you get if you don't divide by 60 and try to get minutes?

Comment: Do you have a DATE column?

Comment: @RajMore: No dude, i am saving only time part

Comment: @Necreaux: but it will not check for last shift either it is in minutes or in hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ShiftOutTime is the time defined Shift Table and
@OutTime is the OutTime of an employee.

I have found the solution and to calculate the overtime i have used this query:

```
CASE 
                WHEN @InTime=@OutTime THEN 0
                WHEN CONVERT(TIME,@OutTime)<@ShiftOutTime THEN 0
                WHEN CONVERT(TIME,@OutTime)<@ShiftOutTime THEN FLOOR(CAST(((24-((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(TIME,@OutTime),@ShiftOutTime))/CAST(60 AS NUMERIC(18,2))))-CAST(0.5 AS NUMERIC(18,2))) AS NUMERIC(18,2)))
                WHEN CONVERT(TIME,@OutTime)=@ShiftOutTime THEN 0
                ELSE (CAST((((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@ShiftOutTime,CONVERT(TIME,@OutTime)))/CAST(60 AS NUMERIC(18,2)))-CAST(0.5 AS NUMERIC(18,2))) AS NUMERIC(18,2)))
                END
```

Thanks for your responses...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4249/2

The key point being divide by 60.0